# Linking a transaction to a Bitcoin user

Tags: transactions, address, privacy, signature, forum

Has anyone tried and perhaps succeeded at linking a transaction to a possibly controversial site (such as Wikileaks) to a Bitcoin forum user by their forum signatures? I know a lot of people disclose their Addresses, and since the WikiLeaks address is well known, one would probably just need some webcrawler and be able to make a connection. Has anything like this ever been done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This](http://anonymity-in-bitcoin.blogspot.ca/2011/07/bitcoin-is-not-anonymous.html) article was written regarding the alleged theft of 25,000 BTC in July 2011. A similar analysis could be done using known addresses and identities, I would imagine.

Comment: Actually, they apparently did - http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-lno9k3rjDjk/TijliwpNIQI/AAAAAAAAAXk/EioKzYD3QX0/s1600/blogForumWikileaks.PNG